# Slow email receiver in postfix configured on Ubuntu

Tags: security, email, postfix, mail, mail-server

We are sending emails to destinations and the email traffic is high but recipient server is not accepting all emails due to their security rules and source emails can't be restricted.

How to deal or configure postfix here that in case of bulk emails, postfix shouldn't delay emails of other domains? In case of bulk emails, active queue grows and it affects the emails of other receiver domains which is not creating any issue.

Comment: I think Postfix is clever enough to deal with such cases.

Comment: When receiver doesnt accept the emails at same rate then active queue grows and it affects other domains as well. Postfix retries to deliver the emails to destination(where emails rejected due to rate control) in specific time and situation got worse if email traffic grows more than 60k, 90k.